# Highlight button without changing Text, BackColor, Enabled?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

**What would be a good way to highlight a button ?**

This is either used or is not allowed to be used:

- don't change `button.Text` (must keep old text)
- don't change `button.BackColor` (buttons are already very colorful)
- don't change `button.Enabled` (is used but not enough)

[image]

The idea is to have something like a RadioButton-group just with normal buttons. The selected button should be easily seen in *the corner of the eye*.

Ideas that I also had:

- **Border / Shading**: Never used that and I don't really have a clue how to change the default button shading or the border style of a single button.
- **Font** (Underline)
- **Image** (didn't try)

Comment: Add a glow to the outer edge? Most just change the pitch / colour of the background... why is the button being colourful stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I don't understand what you mean by that ? Do you mean to increase the brightness of background ? Also the buttons are colorful already. And white is used as well.

Comment: Well you can paint whatever you want if you have control of the button code. Usually just a simple change in colour to a brighter hue signifies a "highlighted" button, but most of the standard ways alter the background colour, which you said you cannot do. What remains is doing stuff with the border of the button, or around the border itself.

Comment: dont have to change the color but what about the shading? make it slightly pail

Comment: What about changing the opacity of the button if the button is already colourful enough. Post a quick screenshot of what the button in question looks like.

Comment: @mini-me But then again, denoting the "selected" button versus the "highlighted" button could be different again. You say highlighted, but then provide radio buttons as an example. Buttons don't usually remain selected once clicked, so are you really looking for more of a toggle switch?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth This question is all about visuals. I want my Button-group to look good. And yes I have the buttons toggled. I would do the logic myself. Just looking for a good way to highlight the 1 button selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, highlighting a button should be done with the `BackColor`, but if you want something different, you can change the look and feel of the `Border` easily. Here is the code implementing one of look and feel for the border:

```
public class ButtonX : Button {
    GraphicsPath border = new GraphicsPath();
    int radius = 3;
    float borderWidth;
    Color borderColor = Color.Orange;
    bool _checked;
    public float BorderWidth {
        get { return borderWidth; }
        set {
            borderWidth = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public Color BorderColor {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set {
            borderColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public ButtonX() {
        BorderWidth = 4;
    }
    public bool Checked {
        get { return _checked; }
        set { 
            _checked = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent) {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        if (Checked) {
            pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            for (float f = BorderWidth; f >= 0.01f; f -= 1f)
            {
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb((int)(100 - 100 * f * f / (BorderWidth * BorderWidth)), borderColor), f))
                {
                    pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
                    pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Center;
                    pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, border);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void UpdateBorder() {
        border = new GraphicsPath();
        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF{Width = radius * 2, Height = radius * 2, X = BorderWidth/2, Y = BorderWidth/2};
        border.AddArc(rect, 180, 90);
        rect.X = ClientSize.Width - BorderWidth/2 - radius * 2 - 0.5f;            
        border.AddArc(rect, 270, 90);
        rect.Y = ClientSize.Height - BorderWidth/2 - radius * 2 - 0.5f;
        border.AddArc(rect, 0, 90);
        rect.X = BorderWidth / 2;
        border.AddArc(rect, 90, 90);
        border.CloseAllFigures();
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        UpdateBorder();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: the `ButtonX` above has a property called `Checked`, you can change this to what you want, it's a property to determine when the `highlighted border` is shown. Just set it to `true` to show the highlighted border. Here are some screen shots (with border of `8`):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem some time ago. The following solution highlights a color, preserving the original color. You could use it to highlight the button back color (but preserving it). Otherwise, you should ownerdraw you button and look for a good mechanism to highlight it (glow, border, etc ...). Hope it helps.

```
public static Color HighLight(Color c)
{
    ColorRGB color = new ColorRGB(c);

    float newLValue = color.L;

    float highlightFactor = 0.25f; //from 0 to 1

    // change lightness
    if (color.L >= 0.5)
    {
        newLValue -= highlightFactor;
    }
    else
    {
        newLValue += highlightFactor;
    }

    ColorRGB highlighted = 
        FromHSLA(
        color.H, 
        color.S, 
        newLValue, 
        color.A);

    return Color.FromArgb(highlighted.A, highlighted.R, highlighted.G, highlighted.B);
}

public class ColorRGB
{
    public byte R;
    public byte G;
    public byte B;
    public byte A;

    public ColorRGB()
    {
        R = 255;
        G = 255;
        B = 255;
        A = 255;
    }

    public ColorRGB(Color value)
    {
        this.R = value.R;
        this.G = value.G;
        this.B = value.B;
        this.A = value.A;
    }
    public static implicit operator Color(ColorRGB rgb)
    {
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(rgb.A, rgb.R, rgb.G, rgb.B);
        return c;
    }
    public static explicit operator ColorRGB(Color c)
    {
        return new ColorRGB(c);
    }


    // Given H,S,L in range of 0-1
    // Returns a Color (RGB struct) in range of 0-255
    public static ColorRGB FromHSL(double H, double S, double L)
    {
        return FromHSLA(H, S, L, 1.0);
    }

    // Given H,S,L,A in range of 0-1
    // Returns a Color (RGB struct) in range of 0-255
    public static ColorRGB FromHSLA(double H, double S, double L, double A)
    {
        double v;
        double r, g, b;
        if (A > 1.0)
            A = 1.0;

        r = L;   // default to gray
        g = L;
        b = L;
        v = (L <= 0.5) ? (L * (1.0 + S)) : (L + S - L * S);
        if (v > 0)
        {
            double m;
            double sv;
            int sextant;
            double fract, vsf, mid1, mid2;

            m = L + L - v;
            sv = (v - m) / v;
            H *= 6.0;
            sextant = (int)H;
            fract = H - sextant;
            vsf = v * sv * fract;
            mid1 = m + vsf;
            mid2 = v - vsf;
            switch (sextant)
            {
                case 0:
                    r = v;
                    g = mid1;
                    b = m;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    r = mid2;
                    g = v;
                    b = m;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    r = m;
                    g = v;
                    b = mid1;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    r = m;
                    g = mid2;
                    b = v;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    r = mid1;
                    g = m;
                    b = v;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    r = v;
                    g = m;
                    b = mid2;
                    break;
            }
        }
        ColorRGB rgb = new ColorRGB();
        rgb.R = Convert.ToByte(r * 255.0f);
        rgb.G = Convert.ToByte(g * 255.0f);
        rgb.B = Convert.ToByte(b * 255.0f);
        rgb.A = Convert.ToByte(A * 255.0f);
        return rgb;
    }

    // Hue in range from 0.0 to 1.0
    public float H
    {
        get
        {
            // Use System.Drawing.Color.GetHue, but divide by 360.0F 
            // because System.Drawing.Color returns hue in degrees (0 - 360)
            // rather than a number between 0 and 1.
            return ((Color)this).GetHue() / 360.0F;
        }
    }

    // Saturation in range 0.0 - 1.0
    public float S
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Color)this).GetSaturation();
        }
    }

    // Lightness in range 0.0 - 1.0
    public float L
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Color)this).GetBrightness();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for a toggle button behavior but mutually exclusive in a group. You can have a group of checkboxes and set it's appearance to button. But the mutually exclusive behavior you will have to handle in code.

Or probably you have can have a group of radio buttons and set it's appearance to button.

```
radioButton1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
```